# coldfusion/runtime/UDFMethod error - component is in java byte code

Tags: java, coldfusion, lucee

I am getting error coldfusion/runtime/UDFMethod error.
Actually my component file (boul.cfc) is in javabyte code (Hex). I am calling method as follows

```
<cfset myBoul = createObject("component", "boul") />
<cfset hash = myBoul .GetmyBoulHash(trim(arguments.text)) />
```

recently we changes Coldfusion to Lucee server.

Can you please help me on this where I missed settings/configurations

> 63 more Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\inetpub\alhpa.boul345.com\WEB-INF\lucee\cfclasses\CFC__inetpub_alhpa_boul_com3428\coldfusion\runtime\UDFMethod.class at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source) at lucee.commons.io.res.type.file.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:243) at lucee.commons.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:190) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.findClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:157) ... 66 more*

Comment: If you look at the error message the cause is: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\inetpub\beta2.iconsumer.com\WEB-INF\lucee\cfclasses\CFC__inetpub_alhpa_boul_com3428\coldfusion\runtime\UDFMethod.class`

Comment: which file not exists? boul.cfc?

my file is under cfc/boul.cfc and calling from cfc/mems.cfc, boul.cfc file is in hex code.
creating object has below
<cfset myBoul = createObject("component", "boul") /> <cfset hash = myBoul .GetmyBoulHash(trim(arguments.text)) />

Comment: Can you dump variable `myBoul` after the first `cfset` command?

Comment: getting the error as I given above error dump

Comment: If this was ACF, the likely cause would be that the cfc was not in a place where CF could find it.  That is, among other things, set up in the Administrator page.  Is there something similar in Lucee?

Comment: FWIW, if the file is showing you Hex code, it's an encrypted CFC file. I'm guessing you don't have access to the unencrypted code and I can't find any reference to in online. Once you fix the CFC mapping issue that @DanBracuk mentioned, you may be missing some support files as well. Were there any CFX or JAR files in the original ACF server?

Comment: Sorry, What's the ACF?

Comment: And we are using Lucee server

Comment: What are the configurations or settings we should use for encrypted CFC, when we use Luceee server?

Comment: This has been resolved. 
The code which is complied in ACF should not be work in Lucee, so we should take a original code file in to lucee and get complied code and use it.

Thanks all for your involvement in this.